# Create dynamic number of rows from xml appcelerator ios

Tags: ios, xml, dynamic, appcelerator, rows

I have created xml file like below :

//cityState.xml

```
<Alloy>
<Window id="cityStateMgWin">
    <TableView  id="cityAndStatesTableView" >
        <TableViewRow  id="cityStatesRow" ></TableViewRow>
    </TableView>
</Window>
```

//In cityState.js

I am trying to create state rows dynamically  with the following code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < cityAndStatesListJSONData.length; i++) {
$.cityAndStatesTableView.appendRow(Alloy.createController('cityStatesRow', {title : cityAndStatesListJSONData[cityStates].cityState}).getView());
}
```

When i run the following error will coming please help me

```
message = "Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new   (require(\"alloy/controllers/\" + name))(args)')";
 [ERROR] :      stack = "createController\nonload";
```

is there any mistake to get the ui element from xml file to controller and create dynamic number of rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does your cityStatesRow controller look like?

Answer (score 1):

A couple suggestions.

1. You have `underscore` available in Alloy
2. You cannot create a controller based on ID, it needs to be an actual controller.

So... looping through your data is easier this way:

```
_.each(cityAndStatesListJSONData, function(cityAndState){

});
```

Next, make a controller `cityStatesRow` for your row. Should look like this

JS File of this controller:

```
if ($.args.data.labelProp){
   $.myLabel.text = $.args.title;
}
```

You can do this with as many items as you like, images, labels etc. Whatever you want in the row.

Within the `_.each` loop you will want to create the controller and pass the data to it:

```
 var controller = Alloy.createController('cityStatesRow', {title : cityAndState.cityState});
```

And now append it to your TableView

```
$.cityAndStatesTableView.appendRow(controller.getView());
```